# A mixture of classification and regression problem

Tags: regression, machine-learning, classification, predictive-models, unbalanced-classes

This is a hypothetical problem: imagine there is a $y \sim x_1, x_2, ...x_{10}$, with 3 of them classification and 7 of them regression(for example there several clusters within 3 dim space that use different regression model.) But we know nothing about the properties before and we want to propose a model as close as possible. Can some expert think of some methodology or processedures that leads to the right/close model?

My thought will be use feature selection to select most important features(for example two features) and plot the figure $y\sim x_p, x_q$. This will help to see if the parameter is classification or regression. But it's not systematic...

Answer (score 1):

It is the nature of $y$, the outcome you're trying to predict/explain, that determines whether you use a regression approach or classification approach.

If $y$ is continuous, e.g. count, cost, profit, etc., then you use a regression approach.

If $y$ is categorical, e.g. yes vs. no, then you use a classification approach.

Both approaches allow both continuous and categorical predictors $x$.

Note: this distinction generally comes up in machine learning; in statistics, both approaches fall under the term 'regression', e.g. logistic regression is for yes/no outcomes.